# How to call multiple variables from another method in java in the code below ( it is a java macro for a computational fluid dynamics solvwer)

Tags: java, variables, methods

I have a code from a java macro that reads as below  the method "`HeaterPorous()"` is called in the method `"execute0()"` The code is as follows:

```
public class mesh_save extends StarMacro {

      public void execute() {
        execute0();
       }

        public double[] HeaterPorous()  
          {
         List variables = new ArrayList();
         Simulation simulation_0 = getActiveSimulation();

        double ret1 promptUserForInput("1st variable", );        
        double ret2 promptUserForInput("2nd variable", );      
        double ret3 promptUserForInput("3rd variable", );        
        double ret4 promptUserForInput("4th variable", );      
        double ret5 promptUserForInput("5th variable", );        


         return new double[]{ret1,ret2,ret5,ret3,ret4};

      }

      private void execute0() {

       Simulation simulation_0 = getActiveSimulation();
       HeaterPorous();     /***this code calls the method HeaterPorous() defined above ***/

      simulation_0.println(ret1);
      simulation_0.println(ret2);
      simulation_0.println(ret3);
      simulation_0.println(ret4);
      simulation_0.println(ret5);
      }
     }
```

I am not able to get the values of variable that i passed from the `HeaterPorous()` method to the `execute0()` method in my output window.. Can anyone tell where I am going wrong...

Thanks in advance

Comment: `double [] array = HeaterPorous();`?? and [learn about Arryas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: assign variable to the result of HeaterPorous and use the values returned

Answer (score 2):

in `execute0` method you are calling `HeaterPorous` method, which returns an array, but you are not storing that value in any variable. Secondly, the returned object is an array, thus you have to extract individual fields from that array, and you cannot use `simulation_0.println(ret1);` these directly.

Ideally code should be

```
double[] retArr = HeaterPorous(); 
simulation_0.println(retArr[0]);
[...]
```